# How model objects are sorted in Django

Tags: django, django-models

What is performed behind the scenes for the following code: `sorted(MyModel.objects.all())`?

Is it `__lt__`? How is it defined?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just converts queryset into a list and tries to sort the objects. Since I don't think Django has defined a default implementation of comparison methods in model's base class, so most likely it is sorting them on the basis of a random parameter like the memory address.

If you want the database to sort it for you, then you would either have to use [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) provided by the queryset or you can provide `key` to sorted method itself.

```
sorted(MyModel.objects.all(), key='pk')
```

Comment: How does it try to sort them? By what field?

Comment: It doesn't seems Django has default comparision methods defined for `models.Model`. So most likely it is sorting on the basis of memory address of the objects.

Comment: My pleasure. By the way, you can use `id` construct to confirm if that's indeed the case.

Comment: How should I do it?

Comment: Well, `id(model_object)` would return its memory address. You can store the sorted models in a list and confirm if their memory addresses are in same order as well.

Comment: Yes, indeed, that's true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ordering field on Model's Meta for defining a field to sort.

```
ordering = ['-order_date'] # order_date field reverse sorted
```

Look for more information: [Model Meta Ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#ordering)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in Python 3 at least, this code will give you an error:

```
'<' not supported between instances of 'MyModel' and 'MyModel'
```

This is because, as noted in other answers, `models.Model` does not define any comparison methods; in this case Python does not guess, as recommended by the Zen of Python:

> In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.